# Wordpress Snapchat: Pass Email data

Tags: wordpress, snapchat

I have added the Snap Pixel Code in the head, which includes: 'snaptr('init', 'ID', { 'user_email': '**INSERT_USER_EMAIL**' });'

I now have to pass on the email variable but don't know how to do this.

I am using Contact Form 7 in Wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question I understand that you're looking to integrate the Snap Pixel into Wordpress.

You can use something like:

```
<?php
$email = "test@test.com"; //your mail address
?>
<script>
snaptr('init', 'ID', { 'user_email': <?php echo $email; ?> });
</script>
```

You can also use a Wordpress Snap Pixel plugin, see for example: https://wordpress.org/plugins/snap-pixel/#installation

Comment: Do you know how to add a dynamic value filled out in Contact Form 7? Such as text input in a field marked as 'your-email', for example.

Comment: You can use this code snippet: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/309764/21370 or this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/